# Is it bad design to make your business(service) layer dependant on a user session?

Tags: java, architecture, ejb

In a common MVC designed applicaton, is it a bad idea to make the service layer dependant on a user session? Let's say there is a service method that fetches a few objects from a database, and you wish to return different results depending on who initializes the call - for example an administrator might get 10 rows of objects, while a normal user might only get 7 rows because the last 3 were "administrator-only" objects. A few ways to solve this would be:

- Introduce a new method parameter where you include the calling user. Dependancy-less but cumbersome to have to throw in user parameters in many methods.
- Make different methods for different user roles (with multiple results). Also dependancy-less but lots of methods which does basicly the same thing, which increases the risk of code duplication.
- Let the method read from a ThreadLocal variable in a static context storing the current user session. This variable is set before each request.

Lately, i've started using the last method more and more since it provides a clean interface and feels very practical to work with. A Filter makes sure that the current thread always has a user set. Is this bad design? I believe that some could see this as a dependancy from the service layer to the web layer, though I personally think that they are pretty uncoupled. The biggest consequence is that a methods behaviour will be different depending on the state of another class, which could be both a bad and a good thing.

What are your thoughts on this? If it's a bad solution, what would be a stronger one?

Answer (score 5):

I strongly advise aginst ThreadLocal style approaches - it seems like too much of a "global variable" design smell. This has many issues, most notably:

- Your code gets **harder to test** as you go down the slippery slope of having more and more implicit global state to set up before testing
- You **lose the ability to see clearly** what parameters a certain piece of code is working with. This can be very confusing for maintainers or if you come back to the code after a few months.
- It can cause **very nasty bugs / complexity** if you ever hand off work to **different threads**. You've effectively made your code execution dependent on which thread it is running on.... what can possibly go wrong? :-)
- You are creating **circular dependencies** (service layer <-> user interface layer). Never a good idea, you should try to keep dependencies flowing one way only (almost always user interface layer -> service layer)

Between the other two approaches, I think "it depends":

- If the user is intrinsically part of the data model (e.g. you have a social graph database) then it would seem natural to pass the user as a parameter.
- If the user data is just used for front-end stuff like authentication etc. then I would tend towards minimising the dependency on specific user details and instead create different methods for different roles (or equivalently add a "role" parameter).

An alternative option is to pass a "context" object through to the service layer that contains a set of relevant session data (i.e. more than just the user name). This could make sense if you want to minimise parameter bloat. Just beware of it turning into a way to "get around" good layering principles. If it's just "data" then it's probably fine, but as soon as people start passing callback objects / UI components in the context then you are probably heading towards a bit of a mess....

Comment: >it would seem natural to pass the user as a parameter. Why??? EJB already provided you access to the roles of the user, and from the problem statement that's all OP needs.

Comment: @dexter - sure that would make sense if you are using EJB for user roles / security - the question doesn't specify this though.

Comment: @mikera Uhm, the question was tagged with EJB, wasn't it? And since they are the dedicated bean to implement services, it seems clear that OP is using EJB to implement them. You are right that OP should have been MUCH clearer here.

Comment: Hmm didn't spot the EJB tag. If so then using the standard EJB mechanism makes sense. Although from an architectural perspective, it is just another mechanism for passing a set of context parameters so my general advice is still applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Just use Java EE's role mechanism, it's already there.

As an example:

```
@Stateless
public class AService {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<AObject> fetchAFewObjects() {

        String query = "aUserQuery";      

        if (sessionContext.isCallerInRole("ADMIN")
            query = "aAdminQuery";

        return entityManager.createNamedQuery(query, AObject.class)
            .getResultList();    
    }  
}
```

On the web side, make sure you're doing a [container login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), so the server is aware of the logged-in user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to implement either solution for your usecase.

In EJB, what you want is already supported by the framework. It's called the security context and it automatically propagates into every method you call (behind the scenes it's indeed often implemented by TLS, but that's an implementation detail).

This security context will give you access to the username and his/her roles. In your case all you seem to need is to check for the roles.

You can do this declaratively by using annotations on your methods (@RolesAllowed), or by injecting the EJB session context and asking it for the roles of the current user.

Comment: Interesting idea, though in my case I have some user metadata that's needed aswell as the roles. I should have mentioned this more clearly in my question. The security system in my application is slightly more fine grained, allowing roles for dynamic objects.

Comment: @rasmusfranke okay, so it depends what this meta data exactly is. You'll also have access to the user name via the security context, and that can possibly be used as a key to retrieve this meta data with (eg from a DB or explicit Cache like Infinispan). It depends on your exact requirements if this method is feasible or not.

Comment: True, but I'd rather introduce an extra method parameter rather than having to do a DB read! Especially when the calling client method already has this information.

Comment: @rasmusfranke Sure, I hear you. If it concerns data that is in a DB as well (meaning the client doesn't have the only unique version), you can safe the actual DB read by using the JPA L2 cache. In my methods I do em.findById(userId); and it returns instantly. In effect, the JPA L2 is your global state and the security context provides you the key into this state.

Answer (score 1):

From an architecture perspective, I think your last option is the only sane one.

1. Presents a security risk. You would end up having to validate the username against the user information in session (or through any other security mechanism), which effectively invalidates any advantage this might have (as you'd have to already know the user's name/role anyway).
2. Is not really practical nor scalable. Imagine you need to add another role that requires more information (not just more records). Then you'd have methods for your existing 2 user roles and another set for the new role, probably with a different signature and *if-if-if* logic to handle the different scenarios. That tends to get messy, really, really fast and leads to severe maintenance problems.

If you look into web frameworks in Java, you'll notice they use the last approach. They also put the user information into a more "abstract" entity (identity, context, etc.) and advocate the use of roles instead of user names when dealing with information stratification. This way it's much easier to manage the complexity that exists in larger user bases, where there are multiple roles requiring different information views. It's just a matter of adding roles to user profiles.

As reference, see Seam's implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.seam/jboss-seam/2.0.0.GA/org/jboss/seam/contexts/Contexts.java#Contexts.

**Update due to comment are not having sufficient space**

From your commend below, it seems you are coupling your service and UI layer, then. That may only happen if you never expect external entities to consume your service layer. That may be fine, it just depends on your scenario.

Apart from that, I agree with Mikera's but only to a certain point. `ThreadLocal`s are not global in the sense a static value is global. To your service layer the user's information is certainly global and it makes sense to segregate it from standard business information. Also remember that you may have other such information that needs to be stored. What if you need the user's country or language or currency?

`ThreadLocal`s present an effective and performant solution. Not perfect? Surely not but it's somewhat cleaner than other solutions if implemented correctly. That said, it does require some effort to build a proper and foolproof implementation but that can be said of just about anything.

Comment: 1. Is not really a security risk - the method is only called locally so I have full control over what roles can call which methods. 2. I agree with. What do you think about Mikeras concerns in his answer? I think he has some valid points.

Comment: @RasmusFranke - please see the updated answer as the comment box does not have enough space to accomodate of my response.